# How to get font family from other class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have two elements with different class and have option panel to change font family. but one element does not have any option to change font.
i use this code to get font-family from another class and set to first element. but not work.

```
  var font = $('.first-element').css("font-family");
  $('.second-element').css('font-family', font);
```

please help me to set font family to forst class from second class

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide more details on "doesn't work": are you getting any error message in the console, is it just failing silently, ... ?

Comment: Your code works great here. Show more code, pls.

Comment: There is no issue with the code you have provided, if  your first-element has a CSS property set for font-family that is different from the default property for the page, it should work without issue. Perhaps you should also include the code for your options panel as well so we may be able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks all for time to help me. i use wrong code before this and use wrong way to say my problem. I now use > font-family:inerhit and worked

Comment: @masoudnkh, If you solved your problem, and it was the slightest mistake, then delete your question, pls. Because your question won't do SO.